# Why does "for (index, (a, b)) in dict.enumerated()" produce an error?

Tags: swift, for-loop, dictionary, swift3

I tried to loop through a dictionary:

```
let someDict = [...]
for (index, (a, b)) in someDict.enumerated() {

}
```

It shows me an error:

> cannot express tuple conversion '(offset: Int, element: (key: String, value: String))' to '(Int, (String, String))'

This is really weird. Because if we compare the required tuple:

```
(offset: Int, element: (key: String, value: String))
```

with the tuple type in the for loop:

```
(Int, (String, String))
```

They are compatible!

Why is this happening?

Note, I understand that dictionaries don't have a specific order, hence knowing the index of the KVP is not very useful. But I still want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot tell *why*, but `for (index, (key: a, value: b)) in someDict.enumerated()` works.

Comment: This is possibly related to [SR-922](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-922), where the type-checker sometimes fails to match tuples of the same type, but different labels.

Comment: @Hamish But if I use a dictionary like `[Double: String]`, it still fails to compile!

Comment: @Sweeper Not quite sure what you mean. Forgive me if I'm just being dense, but you're already using a dictionary in your example – why would changing the key to be of type `Double` allow it to compile?

Comment: @Hamish You said that this is related to the type checker failing to match tuples of the same types. But it isn't, because if it is, it would have worked if I change the dictionary to `[Double: String]`.

Comment: @Sweeper I said that it's possibly related to the type checker failing to match tuples of the same type, but different labels, because that's what the error message says – "*cannot express tuple conversion '(offset: Int, element: (key: String, value: String))' to '(Int, (String, String))'*". You don't get a radically different error message with a `[Double : String]`.

Comment: Looks fishy. I’ve filed https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)` ["When an element of a tuple type has a name, that name is part of the type."](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448)

I found relying on type inference like so:

```
  let someDict = [...]
  for tuple in someDict.enumerated() {
    let index = tuple.offset
    let a = tuple.element.key
    let b = tuple.element.value

  }
```

avoids having to explicitly type the tuple

```
  var tuple: (offset: Int, element: (key: String, value: String))
```